# PS4: 3 consoles in 3 locations - can I have 1 account?

Tags: ps4, psn

So my company has 3 PS4 consoles in 3 diffrent locations, each using diffrent PSN account and having it's own games. Recently we were wondering - does that makes sense? We, as a company buying a game 3 times, separately for each account. Is there any more reasonable solution to this? Like using 1 account for all PS4 consoles?

Playing online is not that important - game sharing is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you will have to create a new account and use that one. All you need to do is if it is a disk, insert the disk into each console and install it as normal. If it is a digital download then it should be in your library ready for downloading.

Comment: Can I play on 2 accounts simoultanously?

Comment: Not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 2nd question:

No, you can't. You can buy 1 game for 1 account though...the game can be shared on all 3 PS4s...you tell ppl just to log in with the same account and it's gonna be your common account. That's it. Otherwise that would be a loophole in the psn+ system.